# Thymeleaf accessing nested objects

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Can someone please assist on the below? I have an order Object and Item object where there is a many to many relation, I want to iterate through the items of an Order and preview them on the web, below you can see the models and controller(using spring MVC) can someone guide me to how this can be done, I searched a lot but not able to find the proper way.

Error getting

```
Error I'm getting is: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

My entity class is

```
    @Entity
    public class OrderDetail extends Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String branchCode;
    private String ord;
    private String eiclientNumber;
    private String clientOrderNumber;
    private String consigneeP;
    private String paymentTerms;
    private String earliestShipDate;
    private String latestShipDate;
    private String consigneeCode;
    private String billToCode;
    private String thirdPartyBillToCustomerNo;
    private String preferredCarrier;
    private String usd1;
    private String usd2;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orderDetails")
    private Set<ItemDetail>  itemDetails = new HashSet<>();

}
```

And another one is

```
  @Entity
    public class ItemDetail extends Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String branchCode;
    private String ordNo;
    private String detail;
    private String lineNumber;
    private String skuNumber;
    private String qty;
    private String lotNo;
    private String receiptPo;
    private String usd1;
    private String usd2;
    private String usd3;
    private String usd4;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "order_item", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    private Set<OrderDetail> orderDetails = new HashSet<>();
 }
```

And this is the method of my controller

```
@RequestMapping("orders/items")
   public String listItems(Model model){

   List<OrderDetail>  orderDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    orderDetails = orderService.listAll();
    model.addAttribute("items",orderDetails);

    return "orders/items";
}
```

And my html code is

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
                            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Branch Code</th>
                                   <!-- <th>Ord No</th>
                                    <th>Detail</th>-->
                                    <th>Line Number</th>
                                    <!--<th>SKU Number</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Lot No</th>
                                    <th>Receipt Po</th>
                                    <th>USD1</th>
                                    <th>USD2</th>
                                    <th>USD3</th>
                                    <th>USD4</th>-->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                                <tr th:each="item : ${orders.itemDetails}">
                                    <td th:text="${item.id}">123</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.branchCode}">BEY</td>
                                    <!--<td th:text="${item.ordNo}">G012345</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.detail}">PO123</td>-->
                                    <td th:text="${item.lineNumber}">123</td>
                                    <!--<td th:text="${item.skuNumber}">SKU123</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.qty}">25</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.receiptPo}">PO123</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.usd1}">123</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.usd2}">1234</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.usd3}">123456789</td>
                                    <td th:text="${item.usd4}">123456789</td>-->

                                </tr>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all work on your design. You are sending entity object to the view, which is not recommended. Bind the DTO object with the view.

**REGARDING THE NESTED ITERATION:** 
Lets say we have an **Order** object which has a list of **OrderDetail** obejct (in your case set of OrderDetail)

We are adding **a list of Order** object to the model. We want to iterate this Order list and **the list of OrderDetail** that each order has.  The thymeleaf snippet would be like following

```
    <tr>
        <th>OrderId</th>
        <th>OrderDescription</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="order : ${orders}" th:id="'order' + ${order.id}">
        <td th:text="${order.id}">id</td>
        <td th:text="${order.description}">description</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>DetailId</th>
                    <th>DetailDescription</th>
                </tr>
                <tr th:each="detail: ${order.details}">
                    <td th:text="${detail.id}">id</td>
                    <td th:text="${detail.description}">description</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And the output would be like following.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, regarding the design what is not recommended, from some tutorials they are adding the list of all orders to the model and exposing it to the view, which I'm trying to do, so in my example I have OrderDetail and in side it I have a set of ItemDetail and I'm doing the two way mapping there as you can see, when I'm returning the list of OrderDetail I suppose that the set on ItemDetail should be reflecting those orders that are linked to it, shouldn't that be? Is there something I'm missing in the controller?after your example of iteration, that part should be clear to me @Ramjan Ali Ashik

Comment: It is very important to understand hibernate associations rather than having ready the workable code. Please collect some book and start studying the concepts then you will identify the problems by yourself. Thanks!

Comment: The mapping is fine with the DTOs but the thymeleaf iteration is not working, `Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "orders.itemDetails" (template: "orders/items" - line 42, col 37)` and `Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'itemDetails' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?`thanks for your suggestion of the book(s) I already took a Spring course on Udemy and implementing the steps...@Ramjan Ali Ashik

Comment: @EliasKhattar Don't you have `getter` and `setter` methods in your domain class ?

Comment: Yes I do, I almost got it working now, I was referencing wrongly the nesting items, I'm working on finalising it and will post again the correct coding...thanks@Avijit Barua